# How to embed Yandex.Maps on flexbox?

Tags: yandex-maps, yandex-api

How to embed Yandex.Maps on flexbox?

I tried to do it , but if you change the browser window width -- width of the map increases ( it appears the horizontal scrolling).

https://jsfiddle.net/khusamov/91ownd3j/31/

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#map-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#map-block {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#map-settings {
  width: 300px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/khusamov/91ownd3j/43/

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#map-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#map-block {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  position: relative;
}

#map-settings {
  width: 300px;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```